# Как динамически изменить слой у объекта в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Добрый вечер. Как из кода изменить слой у 3D объекта в иерархии[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В любом классе, который наследуется от MonoBehaviour(а это любой класс, который висит на объектах сцены), есть поле gameObject, которое ссылается на объект, на котором висит ваш класс. Через него можно задать слой в виде индекса от 0 до 31.
Например:

gameObject.layer = 1;

[Документация Unity по GameObject.layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/GameObject-layer.html)

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете изменить слой путем присвоения значения для `gameObject.layer`, как уже упоминалось выше. Если вы хотите присвоить нужный вам слой ссылаясь на имя, как выделено у вас в примере в инспекторе, используйте `LayerMask.NameToLayer("Layer")`.

```
gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer('MyLayer');
```